# Backbonejs and defaultRoute

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, web-applications, backbone-routing

I start to learn how to use backbonejs for a web app and I've got a little problem with the defaultRoute when the app is launch.

Here is my script

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "user/:id": "getUser",
        "*actions": "defaultRoute"
    }
});

var app_router = new AppRouter;

app_router.on('route:defaultRoute', function() {
    $("#content").load("pages/page1.html");
});

app_router.on('route:getUser', function(id) {
    $("#content").load("pages/user.php?id="+id);
});

Backbone.history.start();
```

When you go on the App like http://www.myapp.com the defaultRoute is not loaded.

When I click a link not referenced in the routes, page1.html is loaded.

My question is: How can I set the defaultRoute when I go on the app ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code demonstrates a somewhat unusual use of backboneJS, as you're loading complete HTML or pages into a the div container, instead of using backbone views and underscore templates.

Regardless, you may want to consider the following implementation, instead of using the app_router.on(...) syntax.

Consider the following implementation:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "":"defaultRoute" //The router will default to this route if no other routes are matched ("")
        "user/:id": "getUser",
        ...more routes
    },

    defaultRoute:function(){
     ...default route functionality
    },

    getUser:function(id){
     ...
    }
});
```